# Mule - File and https endpoint conflict

Tags: https, mule

I'm encountering the following problem in mule. This is my flow definition:

```
<flow name="httpsTestConnection" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/httpsTestConnection" responseTimeout="10000" />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${hip.home.dir}/online/Requests" responseTimeout="10000"/>
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="${test.connection.service.url}" http:contentType="text/xml" http:method="POST" connector-ref="httpsClientConnector"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${hip.home.dir}/online/Responses" responseTimeout="10000"/>
</flow>
```

I read a request on a certain url, I want to log the message to the Requests folder on the file system.
I send the message to an HTTPS endpoint using 2-WAY SSL.
Afterwards I get the response and log it to the Responses folder on the file system.

Everything works fine if I remove the following line:

```
<file:outbound-endpoint path="${hip.home.dir}/online/Requests" responseTimeout="10000"/>
```

Then the payload is just used to send to the https outbound endpoint.

When the file outbound-endpoint component is specified, the request file is logged, but in the logs I encounter the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content must be set before entity is written
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity.writeRequest(InputStreamRequestEntity.java:177)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
```

Is there a way to make this possible? To use the file:outbound-endpoint and the https:outbound-endpoint together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from the fact the `file:outbound-endpoint` consumes the input produced by the `servlet:inbound-endpoint`, thus preventing the `https:outbound-endpoint` to read the stream.

Add:

```
<object-to-string-transformer />
```

right after the `servlet:inbound-endpoint` to deserialize the inputstream to a string so the message payload can be used by both the `file` and `http` outbound endpoints.